# Timeout error in redis cache

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

I get this error when I cache using azure redis cache. It works in my office network but not with home internet connection. How I can fix this issue.

```
"Timeout performing SET PortalViewds-pup-lounge, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 5, qu: 3, qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 1, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, client Name`enter code here`: USER-PC, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=200,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=4094,Min=200,Max=4095), Local-CPU: 12.78%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that this times out from home, I suspect this is a problem on the client side.  I have compiled a list of the most common causes of timeouts here that you might find helpful.

https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md

In your error message, you don't seem to be running into ThreadPool growth throttling and your client side CPU seems low enough, so it is probably not a CPU problem.  The next thing I would check is the timeout you are using compared to the round-trip time for a small/simple request (which will help you get a feel for the minimum possible latency).  I would also look closely at the size of the key you are trying to get/set to make sure that the bandwidth you have can transfer the size of data in the time allowed.  In general, Redis works best with a large number of small values rather than a few large values.